# How to define an array of floats in Shader properties?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'd like to define an array of floats in my shader, something like this:

```
Properties
{
    _TilesX ("Tiles X", Int) = 10
    _TilesY ("Tiles Y", Int) = 10

    _TileData1 ("Tile data", Float[]) = {} // THIS!!!

    _Texture1 ("Texture odd", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Texture2 ("Texture even", 2D) = "white" {}
}
```

I'm trying to create a single plane that I'll use as a grid and I want to modify the _TileData1 at run-time to change the Y offset of a tile. I'm using _TilesX and _TilesY to get a 2d position of the tile from a 1d array.

Just to be clear, I just want to find out how to define a property type of `float[]` since I couldn't find how to do so on Unity's manual pages or forums.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Apparently not.

I didn't think so, as I'd never seen it, but I thought I'd take a search around and I ran across [this thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/declaring-array-properties-in-shaders.431546/) where the person answering the question says this (emphasis mine):

> You can set arrays from script using `SetFloatArray`, `SetVectorArray`, and `SetColorArray` as of 5.4, **but you can't define an array in the properties.** Basically this means **you can still set the value and have it defined in the CGPROGRAM block to be used, but it won't be serialized** / saved by the material asset or show up in the material editor. It's an odd omission, especially since texture arrays are supported as properties (though texture arrays are a specific type of texture sampler rather than an array of texture properties like color arrays).

So you would be able to use it in the calculation, but you would only be able to modify the value via MonoBehaviour script (and would *need* to).

Answer (score 19):

You can't use properties for `float[]`. But you can use them as variables in your shader and set them from script:

In your shader:

```
CGPROGRAM
int _SegmentsCount = 0;
float _Segments[1000];

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _SegmentsCount; i++) {
        // This is obsviously just an example,
        // avoid loops in shaders if you can help it.
    }
}

ENDCG
```

Then in your script:

```
float [] array = new float[] { 0.25f, 0.75f };
material.SetFloatArray("_Segments", array);
material.SetInt("_SegmentsCount", 2);

renderer.material = material;
```

Comment: So _Segments must have a defined length ? Can't it be changed at run time by c#?

Comment: It can be changed in your C# code. But not in the shader (hence oversizing it to 1000 and requiring passing the length in _SegmentsCount)

Comment: A absolute gem of an answer! Thank you

Comment: Be aware that setting a float array like this means the array will NOT be serialized. So if you set it, and then call AssetDatabase.SaveAssets(), it won't make a difference and when you go to use the material later the values you had previously set will be erased.