# Shader - using PerRendererData with an Array Property

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

In Unity, I can define a shader property with

```
[PerRendererData] _Positions ("Positions", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
```

The PerRendererData will tell Unity to compile the shader in such a way that the _Color property is to be set per renderer, instead of being shared for all renderers using the shader.

However, you [cannot define an array of floats as a Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098671/how-to-define-an-array-of-floats-in-shader-properties).  The Workaround involves setting the value in the CGPROGRAM.

The CGPROGRAM however cannot have the [PerRendererData]

Is there a way to use PerRendererData with a float[]?

Comment: you can use custom editor to making attribute for [Arrays]

Comment: @Jethro did you ever make any progress with this?

Comment: @AdamKDean No sorry, I ended up writing the shader in a different way.  I'd still like to know if it's possible (:

Comment: @Jethro I ended up using material.SetVectorArray/SetFloatArray. Worked perfectly but sadly limited in maximum size, meaning lots of GameObjects with MeshRenderers and MeshFilters.